# How to save toggle state in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would I use localstorage in this code to save the toggle state?

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $(".price-box").fadeToggle(500,"swing");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="price-box">Show/hide this div</div>

<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You mean [How to use LocalStorage](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+localstorage&oq=how+to+use+localstorage&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ?

Comment: My problem is I really don't understand how to use localstorage to save and retrieve the status of the toggled div within my function. I know it's setItem and getItem but I don't know where to put it exactly and how to retrieve the status. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Starting point https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Then you mean something like `toggleState=true; localStorage.setItem("toggleState", toggleState)` then `localStorage.getItem("toggleState")` ? The localStorage is really a super simple API.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand something (as you make rude comments to people helping you here): It's _your job_ to do research and show what you've tried.  Why don't you read the "How to Ask" section of StackOverflow, and then come back and ask a _good_ question.  You have shown **zero effort** on using Local Storage - but yet that's what your question is about.  So why wouldn't we be pointing you at sites that get you going with Local Storage?

Comment: I was trying the whole day to get it working but actually it is NOT super simple for a beginner, so sometimes we need a push in the right direction without pointing to google because that's obviously what we beginners are doing all the time. I'm sure you have been a beginner too once.

Comment: @zlep You are supposed to show your research, what you tried and what failed. We are no mind readers.

Comment: Fair enough - here's a tip for continuing on StackOverflow: a good question on Stack Overflow shows what you've tried, _even if it doesn't work_.  It shows everyone that you aren't just asking "write this for me", but have tried some things (and knowing what you've tried is super useful).

Comment: Actually I did this in the past and my post was edited because I was not focusing on my question, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("price-box") != null) {
    var pb = window.localStorage.getItem("price-box");
    if (pb == "true") {
      $(".price-box").hide();
    }
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    var v = $(".price-box").is(":visible")
    $(".price-box").fadeToggle(500, "swing");
    window.localStorage.setItem("price-box", v)
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nrdz395d/)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. Now I have a better understanding of it. Thanks a lot.